# fullpage.js where am I?

Tags: fullpage.js

I can't see a method in fullpage.js where I can determine the current section and slide. There is a callback for section (afterLoad) but that only tells me the section not the slide. I don't want to have to keep a virtual map in JS of which slide each section is on, but I do need to know in order to show/hide a social sharing icon. Is there a way to access the internals

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, there is only way to get "index" and "slideIndex" where you can get value of current section and slide.

Comment: When you change section, afterLoad (anchorLink, index) gets called, but I also need to know what slide that section is currently displaying...

Answer (score 3):

If you take at [the state classes used by fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) you'll notice it uses a class with the form `fp-viewing-SECTION-SLIDE` as an indicator of the current section and slide.

> A class of the form `fp-viewing-SECTION-SLIDE` is added to the body element of the site. (eg: `fp-viewing-secondPage-0`) The SECTION and SLIDE parts will be the anchors (or indexes if no anchor is provided) of the current section and slide.

You can test it yourself on [the demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and you can look for a use case of this feature on [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

Note as well how the class `active` is used in the active slide and section, which means you can always get the state of the website by using CSS or Javascript.

For example:

```
var activeSection = $('.section.active');
var activeSlide = activeSection.find('.slide.active');
```

And if you want to use a callback such as `afterLoad`, you can always do this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        var loadedSlide = loadedSection.find('.slide.active');
    }
});
```

Or directly check also the `afterSlideLoad` callback.

Comment: Thanks, with a minor change (.index) I was able to achieve what I needed :)

Comment: Please accept the answer( green tick) so it can help future users to access this same question.

Comment: what if you want to get the index in a separate script?

If I try this in a custom script I get: "fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!"